# UIImage not equivalent when encoding/decoding

Tags: json, swift, uiimage, jsondecoder, equatable

I've been doing some tests on my models to make sure they are equal when I encode them into JSON and then decode them back using `JSONEncoder/Decoder`. However, one of my tests failed, and the culprit was `UIImage`. I've made sure that no errors were thrown during the encoding/decoding process.

First of all, this is the test in question:

```
func testProfileImageCodable() throws {
    let image = ProfileImage(UIImage(systemName: "applelogo")!)
    try XCTAssertTrue(assertCodable(image))
}
```

Here's my "Codability" test, where I make sure that types are equal before and after encoding/decoding:

```
func assertCodable<T: Codable & Equatable>(
    _ value: T,
    decoder: JSONDecoder = .init(),
    encoder: JSONEncoder = .init()
) throws -> Bool {
    let encoded = try encoder.encode(value)
    let decoded = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: encoded)
    
    return value == decoded
}
```

Firstly, here's how I made `UIImage` work with `Codable`:

```
extension KeyedEncodingContainer {
    mutating func encode(_ value: UIImage, forKey key: Key) throws {
        guard let data = value.pngData() else {
            throw EncodingError.invalidValue(
                value,
                EncodingError.Context(codingPath: [key],
                debugDescription: "Failed convert UIImage to data")
            )
        }
        try encode(data, forKey: key)
    }
}

extension KeyedDecodingContainer {
    func decode(_ type: UIImage.Type, forKey key: Key) throws -> UIImage {
        let imageData = try decode(Data.self, forKey: key)
        if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
            return image
        } else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(
                DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [key],
                debugDescription: "Failed load UIImage from decoded data")
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The `UIImage` lives in a `ProfileImage` type, so conforming it to `Codable` looks like this:

```
extension ProfileImage: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case image
    }
    
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.image = try container.decode(UIImage.self, forKey: .image)
    }
    
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(self.image, forKey: .image)
    }
}
```

Furthermore, `ProfileImage`'s `Equatable` conformance uses [`isEqual(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobjectprotocol/1418795-isequal) on the `UIImage` property, which [they say](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage) is "the only reliable way to determine whether two images contain the same image data."

Yet, my test still fails, and I'm not sure why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> the only reliable way to determine whether two images contain the same image data

They are wrong about that. That piece of the docs has misled me in the past too!

The way to compare two images for equality of content (the underlying bitmap) is to compare their `pngData`.

---

What's wrong with your code, however, at the deepest level, is that a UIImage has `scale` information which you are throwing away. For example, your original image's `scale` is probably 2 or 3. But when you call `image(data:)` on decoding, you fail to take that into account. If you did take it into account, your assertion would work as you expect.

I tweaked your code like this (there might be a better way, I just wanted to prove that `scale` was the issue):

```swift
struct Image: Codable {
    let image:UIImage
    init(image:UIImage) {
        self.image = image
    }
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case image
        case scale
    }
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let scale = try container.decode(CGFloat.self, forKey: .scale)
        let image = try container.decode(UIImage.self, forKey: .image)
        self.image = UIImage(data:image.pngData()!, scale:scale)!
    }
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(self.image, forKey: .image)
        try container.encode(self.image.scale, forKey: .scale)
    }
}
```

Here's my test:

```
let im = UIImage(systemName:"applelogo")!
let encoded = try! JSONEncoder().encode(Image(image:im))
let decoded = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Image.self, from: encoded)
assert(im.pngData()! == decoded.image.pngData()!)
print("ok") // yep
```

Comment: I see. Yet, it still doesn't work! I changed my test to this:
`func testProfileImageCodable() throws {
    let testImage = UIImage(systemName: "applelogo")!
    
    let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(ProfileImage(testImage))
    let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(ProfileImage.self, from: encoded)
    
    XCTAssertTrue(decoded.image.pngData() == testImage.pngData())
}
`
and it still fails. Maybe it's a problem with how I implemented UIImage's encoding/decoding? (sorry for the formatting, not being to add full code to SO comments is a pain)

Comment: Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/nikitamounier/299e6083d2f0554b48173b2361bef4ad) with the relevant code if that's easier for you to read.

Comment: Yeah, I see what's wrong, you've thrown away the `scale` information.

Comment: I see, great catch! The `scale` information is actually something I most likely don't want to keep, since the UIImage will be displayed multiple times in different sizes throughout the app and in different screen sizes (so I'll let SwiftUI decide at what scale the image should be shown). However, what I will do is create a wrapper struct just for the testing where I will keep the scale information, so that my tests can pass. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh, rewrite the tests to mask the bug? Good idea. Not. :)

Comment: I edited to get rid of the extra property. But to get rid of the scale information entirely would be wrong; they will not be same image and your tests must not pretend they are.

Comment: Doesn't the scale default to 1.0 though? They won't be images loaded into the Assets folder, they'll be coming straight from the user's photo library.

Comment: But that's not what your test tests. You started with `UIImage(systemName:"applelogo")!`. That UIImage does not have scale 1.0.

Comment: Moreover, I do not know for a fact that a UIImage obtained from the user's photo library has scale 1.0. Do you?

Comment: Yes you're right, the `UIImage(systemName: "applelogo")!` is just a placeholder, I'm going to be bundling a mock image with my test package. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624110-scale) says that "If you load an image from a file whose name includes the @2x modifier, the scale is set to 2.0. You can also specify an explicit scale factor when initializing an image from a Core Graphics image. All other images are assumed to have a scale factor of 1.0."

Comment: I therefore assume that a UIImage from a user's photo library has scale 1.0 – but maybe it differs between devices, just like in the Asset.xcassets. For completeness' sake, I think you're right – I'll be encoding/decoding the scale property too.

Comment: Again, do not adjust the test to how you think your code will or will not be used. Either your code can round trip an image — _any_ image — through coding / decoding or it cannot. Otherwise your use of testing is invalid.

Comment: Am I missing something? The problem is that UIImage requires to conform to Codable, right? But in this line `try container.decode(UIImage.self, forKey: .image)` you are passing it to decoder as-is... So how do you solve the Codable issue?

Comment: Should not it be like this - `let image: Data = try container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .image)` ?

Comment: The answer doesn't compile, whats going on? Can you please update? @matt

Comment: @erotsppa Compiles fine for me, what's the issue for you?

Comment: let image = try container.decode(UIImage.self, forKey: .image), UIImage does not conform to codable

Comment: @erotsppa Because you forgot to include the OP's code. This question is about the OP's code. My answer is merely an addition to it. The OP's code is what makes UIImage conform to Codable. My answer merely makes the OP's round-tripping test succeed.

Comment: I see now that @Sirop4ik made the same mistake. It really helps to _read_ the question and the answer.